# R function problem with NA the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be use

Tags: r, function, warnings, na

I have the following function which returns age from an ID:

```
giveAge = function(id){
     # start returns the place where any number starts in the id string
     start = regexpr(id, pattern ="[0-9]")[[1]] 
     # age returns the age by using the year the id was born 
     age  = ifelse(substr(id,start,start) == 0,
            lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (2000 + as.numeric(substr(id,start,start + 1))),
            lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (1900 + as.numeric(substr(id,start,start + 1)))
     )
     return(age)
}
```

For example, say we have a vector with four id's, the third is missing.
(AAHG born in 1975, FFCH in 1991, and CUM in 1955)

```
IDs = c("AAHG7511083A8", "FFCH9108017U2", NA, "CUM550117112")
```

Using `giveAge` in `IDs` we get

```
> giveAge(IDs)
[1] 46 30 NA 66
```

Everything is cool and danddy here, but when the missing value comes first in the vector

```
IDs2 = c(NA, "AAHG7511083A8", "FFCH9108017U2", "CUM550117112")
```

when applying `giveAge` to `IDs2` I get

```
> giveAge(IDs2)
[1] NA NA NA NA
```

I tried fixing the problem by imputing an arbitrary number if the value is NA, but I get a Warning and the function is not applyed over the whole vector :c

```
giveAge2 = function(id){
     if(!is.na(id)){
         start = regexpr(id, pattern ="[0-9]")[[1]] 
      
         age  = ifelse(substr(id,start,start) == 0,
                lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (2000 + as.numeric(substr(id,start,start + 1))),
                lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (1900 + as.numeric(substr(id,start,start + 1)))
         )
         return(age)
     } else {
         return(28)  
     }
}

> giveAge2(IDs2)
[1] 28
Warning message:
In if (!is.na(id)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** The giveAge code in the question calculates start based on only the first element of the input so if that element is NA then everything is NA.  giveAge in the question will work if the [[1]] is removed.

(giveAge2 has the above problem plus it is passing a vector to the if statement but such statements require a scalar.)

**2)** Alternately try this. We have also removed the dependency on packages.  This trims non-digits off the left hand side of each string, takes the first 2 digits of what remains and converts that to numeric giving the 2 digit year yy.  Then it converts that to a 4 digit year giving year and subtracts it from the current year.

```
giveAge3 <- function(id, today = Sys.Date(), cutoff = 10) {
  yy <- as.numeric(substr(trimws(id, "left", "\\D"), 1, 2))
  year <- yy + 1900 + 100 * (yy < cutoff)
  as.numeric(format(today, "%Y")) - year
}

giveAge3(IDs)
## [1] 46 30 NA 66

giveAge3(IDs2)
## [1] NA 46 30 66
```

Comment: Nice solution becoming independent from the packages and using ```trimws``` function. It solved the problem satisfactory. Thank you very much and have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

In the function, create a logical index with `is.na`. Then use the index to extract from the input vector and assign to the return value.

```
giveAge <- function(id){
  # start returns the place where any number starts in the id string
  i_na <- is.na(id)
  age <- rep(NA_real_, length(id))
  start <- regexpr(id[!i_na], pattern ="[0-9]")[[1]] 
  # age returns the age by using the year the id was born 
  age[!i_na] <- ifelse(substr(id[!i_na],start,start) == 0,
                       lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (2000 + as.numeric(substr(id[!i_na],start,start + 1))),
                       lubridate::year(Sys.Date()) - (1900 + as.numeric(substr(id[!i_na],start,start + 1)))
  )
  age
}

IDs = c("AAHG7511083A8", "FFCH9108017U2", NA, "CUM550117112")
IDs2 = c(NA, "AAHG7511083A8", "FFCH9108017U2", "CUM550117112")

giveAge(IDs)
#[1] 46 30 NA 71
giveAge(IDs2)
#[1] NA 46 30 71
```

Comment: Nice solution creating a mask of NA's and filling it with the desired info. I wish I could upvote somehow your answare. Thank you. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

`is.na(id)` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` for every value in `id`. Since `id` is set to `c(NA, "AAHG7511083A8", "FFCH9108017U2", "CUM550117112")` in your example, the output of `is.na(id)` will be `TRUE, FALSE, FALSE; FALSE`.

The `if()` function, however, expects only one value (a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`). Without checking the rest: If the problem only arises "when the missing value comes first in the vector", you can check whether the first value is `NA` simply by using `if(!is.na(id[1]))`

Comment: The Warning is not returned, but is only applied to the first element in the vector. This doesn't solve the problem entirely.